# How can I create a polymorphic "map xs f" function?

Tags: coq, parametric-polymorphism

### The statement of the problem.

Consider this definition of `map`:

```
Fixpoint map (xs: list nat): (nat -> nat) -> list nat := match xs with
| nil => fun _ => nil
| x::xs' => fun f => (f x) :: (map xs' f)
end.
```

It works like this:

```
Coq < Eval simpl in map (1::2::3::List.nil) (fun x => x + 1).
     = 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: nil
     : list nat
```

How can I extend it to work on any types?

For example, in Haskell I can simply write as follows:

```
map :: forall a b. [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
map xs = case xs of
    [ ]     -> \_ -> [ ]
    (x:xs') -> \f -> f x: map xs' f
```

But in Coq, I do not understand where I could place this `forall` quantifier.

### My efforts.

[The syntax reference](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.fixpoint) explains the syntax of `Fixpoint` thusly:

> `Fixpoint ident binders {struct ident}? : type? := term`

— So evidently there is no place in the syntax for a quantifier that binds a type variable over both *binders* and *type*. I tried placing `forall` here and there by guesswork but I could not make it work.

I can see how the *type* section could be made polymorphic in the result type of the function parameter without touching the *binders* section:

```
Fixpoint map (xs: list nat): forall B, (nat -> B) -> list B := match xs with
| nil => fun _ => nil
| x::xs' => fun f => f x :: (map xs' f)
end.
```

— But unfortunately this also gives an error, and cryptic enough for me at that:

```
In environment
map : list nat -> forall B : Type, (nat -> B) -> list B
xs : list nat
T : Type
The term "nil" has type "list ?A" while it is expected to have type
 "(nat -> T) -> list T".
```

So, even for this simpler case I have no solution.

#### So, what can be done?

Comment: Note that you can also `Print map.` to see how it is done in the standard library.

Comment: The cryptic error message that is tripping you up here is that in Haskell, type parameters are only mentioned in the type.  In Coq they are actual arguments to the function, and are not implicit by default.  The error you get is equivalent to what you'd get in Haskell if you wrote `... case xs of
    [ ]     -> [ ] ...` and left the rest of your code the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Coq, the `Fixpoint` command is just a wrapper around the `fix` term constructor, which allows us to define anonymous recursive functions.  A direct definition of `map` could be given as follows:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition map_anon : forall A B, (A -> B) -> list A -> list B :=
  fix map A B (f : A -> B) (l : list A) : list B :=
    match l with
    | [] => []
    | x :: l => f x :: map A B f l
    end.
```

This is morally equivalent to the following definition:

```
Fixpoint map A B (f : A -> B) (l : list A) : list B :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | x :: l => f x :: map A B f l
  end.
```

Notice that `A` and `B` are bound as regular variables: in Coq, there is no distinction between types and terms, and these declarations causes Coq to infer their types as being `Type`.  No `forall` quantifier is needed for the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all your arguments, including type arguments, after the name of the function. You'll put any arguments that depend on other arguments after the argument they depend on.

```
Fixpoint map (A B: Type) (xs: list A) (f: A -> B): list B :=
[...]
```

If you prefer `forall`s, you simply need to move everything (except the recursive argument and any arguments it depends on) to after the `:`.

```
Fixpoint map (A B: Type) (xs: list A): forall (f: A -> B), list B :=
[...]
```

Two things to note here. Since nothing after `f` depends on `f`, you could use the `->` notation. This is purely notation and doesn't have any semantic difference.

```
Fixpoint map (A B: Type) (xs: list A): (A -> B) -> list B :=
[...]
```

The other thing to note is that when the arguments are after the `:` like this, we have to define a function, not just something in `list B`.

```
Fixpoint map (A B: Type) (xs: list A): (A -> B) -> list B :=
fun f => [...]
```

This is why you got the error `The term "nil" has type "list ?A" while it is expected to have type "(nat -> T) -> list T".`. We needed a function, not just something of type `list B`, which is what `nil` is.

Comment: The `Fixpoint` command cannot be used as you suggests, it has to take at least one argument explicitly (the recursive argument), so only your first example is correct.